# Векторизация значений (перевод 3 столбцов в матрицу) / PIVOT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pivot

Стоит следующая задача, оптимально решить задачу векторизации 3 столбцов.

Смысл задачи: eсть 50 категорий и 10000 магазинов, которые могут иметь товары из этих категорий, но все это в 3 столбцах:

```
id_shop category qnty
 1          1      50
 1          2      32
 1          15     44
 2          1      333
 2          4      33
 2          5      15
 2          15     12 
 2          35     14
 3          3      14
 ....
```

А надо это все сделать в виде вектора (или матрицы), где строки это `id` магазинов, а столбцы это категории, а пересечение строк и столбцов, соответственно количество товаров в магазине по данной категории. Если в данном магазине товаров данной категории нет, то ставится ноль. И получается:

```
id_shop/category 1   2   3   4 ... 15  16.... 35  36.... 
  1              50  32  0   0     44  0      0   0 
  2              333 0   0   33    12  0      14  0
  3              0   0   14  0     0   0      0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.pivot(index = 'id_shop', columns = 'category', values = 'qnty')
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще несколько вариантов:

`set_index()` + `unstack()`:

```
In [7]: df.set_index(['id_shop','category'])['qnty'].unstack('category', fill_value=0)
Out[7]:
category   1   2   3   4   5   15  35
id_shop
1          50  32   0   0   0  44   0
2         333   0   0  33  15  12  14
3           0   0  14   0   0   0   0
```

`pivot_table()`:

```
In [8]: df.pivot_table(index='id_shop', columns='category', values='qnty', fill_value=0)
Out[8]:
category   1   2   3   4   5   15  35
id_shop
1          50  32   0   0   0  44   0
2         333   0   0  33  15  12  14
3           0   0  14   0   0   0   0
```

`df.groupby()` + `mean()` + `unstack()`:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['id_shop','category'])['qnty'].mean().unstack('category', fill_value=0)
Out[11]:
category   1   2   3   4   5   15  35
id_shop
1          50  32   0   0   0  44   0
2         333   0   0  33  15  12  14
3           0   0  14   0   0   0   0
```

`pd.crosstab()`:

```
In [19]: pd.crosstab(index=df.id_shop, columns=df.category, values=df.qnty, aggfunc='mean').fillna(0)
Out[19]:
category     1     2     3     4     5     15    35
id_shop
1          50.0  32.0   0.0   0.0   0.0  44.0   0.0
2         333.0   0.0   0.0  33.0  15.0  12.0  14.0
3           0.0   0.0  14.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```